# string s lowerCase conversion with [^a-zA-Z0-9]

Tags: java, expression

There is a string `s`, and I saw a code which is :

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
```

What is the reason to use this kind of code? What does it do?

This is the full solution :

```
public static boolean isValidPalindrome(String s){
    if(s==null||s.length()==0) return false;

    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";

    System.out.println(isValidPalindrome(str));
}
```

Comment: I am trying to solve a palindrome question, and there is a solution in programming creek web-site and used this expression to solve it.

Comment: From `replaceAll` documentation you can learn that this method accepts regular expression and from regex tutorials you can learn that `[^a-zA-Z)-9]` is [negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

Answer (score 1):

The regex matchs all characters which are NOT a-z or A-Z or 0-9.
These chars are replaced with nothing, saying removed from the string.
Then everything is converted to lower case.

So you end up with a string which only contains numbers and lower case letters. That could be important for user input you want to clean up or similar

Answer (score 1):

The Regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will **delete** (replace by `""`) any characters **different** from `A to Z` and `0 till 9`.
After that, it will **lowercase** (`.toLowerCase()`)  all remaining characters in the string, i.e. :

```
String s = "abc&AA_";
```

will become:

```
abcaa
```

---

**LIVE EXAMPLE**

http://ideone.com/ZzemM5

Answer (score 0):

This basically converts the string in to lower case and removes any additional value  with "" except for Numbers from a 0-9 and Alphabets from a to z .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).